# Compare changes in two different CodeMirror textareas

Tags: textarea, diff, codemirror

I am trying to use two different `textarea`s displaying the same code, but with one master, and another copy. In the copy `textarea`, I would like to highlight changes, something similar to what GitHub offers when we do some changes.

I was wondering if this is possible or if someone did something similar before. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: But reading your question more closely, it seems you want an inline diff inside the editable code, rather than a separate uneditable diff like GitHub shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [CodeMirror Merge add-on](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_merge) is exactly what you want. See the [demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html), which matches your description.

---

At first I thought you wanted a separate diff, displayed in a `div` *below* your `textarea`s rather than *inside* one of the `textarea`s, and I wrote the following answer. It may still be useful.

> Check out the [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library, used by the [CodeMirror Merge add-on](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html). It’s not a drop-in solution, but it looks like you could use [`diff_main`](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API) to get a list of original and changed text, and then display that yourself. The library also provides `diff_prettyHtml`, which outputs example markup for the diff.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot Rory

Comment: The example is not working with textareas that's a bit confusing, where are the two textareas defined ?

Comment: If you view the source of [the example](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html), you can see that one textarea is defined with `var target = document.getElementById("view");` `dv = CodeMirror.MergeView(target, {…});`.  The other is defined by passing [the `origLeft` option](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_merge), which creates its own `textarea`: `origLeft: panes == 3 ? orig1 : null`. (The value passed to the `origLeft` and `orig` options represent the strings to populate their respective `textarea`s with.)

Comment: It is almost working but still have a problem with the CSS, the two textareas are placed one above the other and seem not linked when I scroll one, also highlighting doesnt work yet, almost there

Comment: Done ! Thanks for your help, I had to upgrade version

Answer (score 1):

[Mergely](http://www.mergely.com/) is another option that produces very nice visual diffs using CodeMirror and is distributed under the GPL, LGPL and MPL licenses. It's [GitHub repo is here](https://github.com/wickedest/Mergely).

Also [Prettydiff](http://prettydiff.com/) which isn't very pretty, but when you click the "execute" button at the bottom you get an interesting visual diff. Not sure if the diff itself is using codemirror or just the two input texts that the diff is generated from.